# How microtime works in php

Tags: php

PHP mico time , i want to process my application using microtime

Comment: What do you mean *process my application* ?

Comment: I think, that psr123 is talking about application profiling. XDebug will help you a lot with debugging and profiling your apps.

Answer (score 3):

I think the script example from [PHP.net](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php), for PHP5, is pretty straight forward.

```
<?php
// Put this at the start of your script
$time_start = microtime(true);

// This is where your script should be executing,
// but instead, we sleep for a while
usleep(100);

// Calculation at the end of the script
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

// Do something with the results
echo "Did nothing in $time seconds\n";
?>
```